# Change height and width of video taken from photos of iPhone

Tags: video, size, uiimagepickercontroller, frame, photos

I want to change height and width of a video taken from iPhone gallery/photos.
Is this possible?

How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your question, but I don't think it's a good fit as it is - if you want to do this programmatically, you sould show what you've tried and where you got stuck, and if not, it's not really a question for Stack Overflow (might fit for Superuser or Ask Different).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org), a video manipulation command line tool, to do this. See for example:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg

One way you can use ffmpeg in applications is to encapsulate the ffmpeg program in a wrapper written in a language that your platform supports. I have only done this with Android personally but there are several iOS ffmpeg wrappers you might want to look at, for example:

- https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper

Comment: i want to do this in my swift application

Comment: It would be good to update your question to say this - you may get some more specific answers. I've updated this answer to include reference to ffmpeg iOS wrappers.